# Customizing SQL Server delimiter using query

Tags: sql, sql-server, delimiter

I am writing a query in SQL Server that its output a table.

I want the query result delimiter to be `#|#`, how can I do that?

So if I output it to txt/csv file, it should look like this:

[image: Output result]

Comment: SQL Server doesn't output to CSV (files); so define in what ever your ETL layer is that the delimiter is `#|#`. How you do that completely depends on the application you're using for your ETL; you haven't told us what that is.

Comment: Queries return results sets, not tables, and have no delimiters. Client tools display the results using grids or text, or saving the results to text files like CSVs

Comment: If you use Python, you can use Pandas to load query results and save it as CSV. In all supported SQL Server versions (ie 2017 and later) you can execute Python scripts through the `sp_execute_external_script` stored procedure

Comment: Thanks for both. For now I just  want to it inside the SSMS if it will work I will move it to app. there is any way to that ? using command or something?

Comment: The Import/Export Wizard in SSMS can export results as text and allows you to specify delimiters. The wizard actually generates an SSIS package that can be saved and executed again, eg on a schedule. It can also be edited using SQL Server Database Tools, a separate download

Comment: What does `#|#` get you that `|` doesn't? Why add 3 bytes per column when 1 byte will do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your query to be run in an app then you could use a simple query such as

```
declare @demo table ([name] nvarchar(30), [lastname] nvarchar(50));
insert into @demo([name],[lastname]) values
('Catherine','Aragorn'),
('Anne','Boleyn'),
('Jane','Seymour'),
('Anne','Cleeves');

select concat([name],'#|#',[lastname])
from @demo;
```

Or You can export results to a csv using csv.py using `#|#` as the delimiter - see [CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: Why concatenate in SQL when you're using Python?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I missed the word "Or" from that last line of my solution, I will update it, thank you. However - concatenating in SQL because the OP asked for a SQL query